# Concatenate a selector to variable

Tags: jquery, variables, selector

Trying to concatenate a variable to a selector:

```
<a href="#" class="hover" data-name="dressitup">

     var changer =  $(this).attr("data-name");

         $('a.'+changer).addClass("active");
```

this doesn't work. I obviously want the result to be

```
$(a.dressitup).addClass("active");
```

Comment: What is the result of `'a.'+changer`?  You most certainly can concatenate strings, so perhaps the problem is in populating a value in `changer`?

Comment: What is `$(this)` referring to?

Comment: You could try `$(this).data("name")`. However, as Grant says, what's `this`, actually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `$(this)` is your `a` element: is this what you need?

**jQuery**:

```
var changer =  $(".hover").data("name");
$('a.' + changer).addClass("active");
```

**Markup:**

```
<a href="#" class="hover" data-name="dressitup">Hello World</a>
<br/>
<a href="#" class="dressitup">Hello World 2!</a>
```

**JSFiddle**:
http://jsfiddle.net/sWZzD/